# ASIHTTPRequest problems on iPhone (memory?)

Tags: nsurlconnection, iphone, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest on the iPhone to make a call to the server, which then sends a response containing a JSON file.  I got it working on a basic level, but when I added it to my project, and made a call to the server, my app started crashing with bad_access.

I make the call from viewDidLoad as such:

```
requestModel = [[RequestModel alloc]init];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL URLWithString:@"myURL"]retain];
[requestModel eventsRequestFor:@"myUsername" password:@"myPassword" forURL:url];
```

This calls a function in another class called RequestModel, and I go through and try to unpack the returned array as such (a lot of code):

```
-(void)eventsRequestFor:(NSString*)username password:(NSString*)password forURL:(NSURL*)forURL  {
//use ASIHTTPRequest to post to sever.  Here you authenticate and recieve answer
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:forURL];
[request setUsername:username]; 
[request setPassword:password]; 
[request setDelegate:self];

[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadFailed:)];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadFinished:)];
[request startAsynchronous];

[request release];
NSLog(@"Model called");
}

#pragma mark Model Delegates
- (void)uploadFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request  {
// Use when fetching text data

NSLog(@"upload start");
NSString *stringFromRequest = [[NSString alloc]init];
stringFromRequest = [request responseString];

[self buildArrayFromRequest:stringFromRequest];

//[stringFromRequest release];
}

- (void)uploadFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request  {
NSString *statusMessage = [request responseStatusMessage];
NSLog(@"%@",statusMessage);
NSError *error = [request error];
NSLog(@"%@",error);

}   

-(void)buildArrayFromRequest:(NSString*)string  {

NSArray *arrayFromData = [[NSArray alloc]init];
arrayFromData = [string yajl_JSON];
NSLog(@"This is the array from the JSON  %@",[arrayFromData objectAtIndex:0]);
NSMutableArray *events = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

for(int i= 0; i < [arrayFromData count];i++)
{
    /////code to unpack array

}

       ///here i try to populate table with unpacked array
FirstViewController *firstVC = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
[firstVC createTableWithArray:events];

[firstVC release];
[arrayFromData release];
[events release];

}
```

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?  It seems like I am releasing an object that has already been released, but I can't find it.

Comment: Can you post the call stack (from in the debugger) as well please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: You're releasing an NSData that's not yours.

You don't need this line :

```
[arrayFromData release];
```

because of this mistake :

You have put :

```
NSArray *arrayFromData = [[NSArray alloc]init];
arrayFromData = [string yajl_JSON];
```

when all you need is this :

```
NSArray *arrayFromData = [string yajl_JSON]; // This doesn't need releasing
```

---

You're releasing a request that's already autoreleased :(

```
// Create an autoreleased request object
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:forURL];

...

[request release]; // fail here - this line is not needed
```

---

Just FYI :

This is unneeded code :

```
NSString *stringFromRequest = [[NSString alloc]init];
stringFromRequest = [request responseString];
```

You are making a string object and then getting a different one. The first one you're making will be leaked. This code will do what you want :

```
NSString *stringFromRequest = [request responseString]; // This doesn't need releasing :)
```

However, it's the cause of a leak, not the crash that you are reporting.

(You've got this pattern in other places in your code, not just here.)

Comment: That's actually not the error.  I deleted it and the app still crashes.  In a forum I read that ASIHTTPRequest could be making the error of calling the server twice, so I thought that if I released request then I would prevent that function.  However, releasing request, and keeping it both make my app crash with the same error.

Comment: Ha ha - after a while you begin to learn what to look for :) I've been making memory management bugs for about two years now!